# forward outgoing traffic port using iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I am trying to forward all outgoing traffic from port 80 to port 8080 using `iptables` and I tried the following rule, though it did not work:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j  REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Also, for incoming traffic I need a rule that forward port on the same host not to be as proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need that under `nat`

e.g

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

you can run this: with example of forwarding 80 to 8080 and so on...

Incoming on 80 to 8080

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Outgoing on 80 to 8080

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-ports 8080
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

Comment: thank u 
i found this rule and it worked
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination  :8080